# Problems with headers using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the following code in a thesis template that can be found in overleaf:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{0pt}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
```

However, even though I am using `\nouppercase\leftmark`, the name of the chapter still appears uppercase. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Edit:

The chapter name, let us say called "Introduction", --- own chapter, not generated by LaTeX --- appears as "INTRODUCTION", instead of "Introduction". Is there any other command, besides `\nouppercase`to control this?

Comment: The name of which chapter? Maybe things like `CONTENTS` or `BIBLIOGRAPHY`?, i.e not your own chapters but the thing LaTeX generates? These things sometimes escape the `\nouppercase` mechanism. Otherwise please give a bit more information, like what documentclass, and packages you use. Preferably give a very short, but complete document that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'm very sorry. It seems the definition of `\MakeUppercase` has changed in the latest LaTeX release. This macro cause the uppercasing and `\nouppercase` tries to counteract that within the `fancyhdr` headers and footers. But with the new definition of `\MakeUppercase` it fails to do so. I have a patch which I will release as soon as possible, i.e within a few days. In the meantime, if you can't wait for that, write me an email (see the `fancyhdr` doc) and I will send you an updated version.